# cruisecontrol email notification

Tags: email, cruisecontrol

Is there easy way to send email notification with cruise control?
I Was reading the documentation about this tool and I did not find any destination mail in 
 or  tag?
I see "returnaddress" field but no destination address.
Could someone help me out with that?
Thank you on advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destination is evaluated according to the user, that made the change.

You have to provide a mapping for the users:

```
<plugin name="htmlemail" mailhost="notes01" 
        spamwhilebroken="false" 
        returnaddress="reply_to_address" subjectprefix="[CRUISECONTOL]" >
    <map Address="unresolved_external@mycompany.org" Alias="unresolved_external" />
    <ignore user="ignored_user_name" />
    <failure address="failreport@mycompany.org" reportWhenFixed="true"/>
  </plugin>
```